# Could not find fixture: fitlibrary.spider.SpiderFixture

Tags: selenium, fitnesse, web-testing, fitlibraryweb

I try to set up Fitnesse with FitLibraryWeb for Selenium based web tests. The tutorial test at `/FitLibraryWeb.SpiderFixture.SpiderTutorial.StartingWithSpider` works (I changed the driver from firefox to chrome but that should not matter), but if I create my own test page, it always aborts with said error message **[1]**.

I even copied the exact content of the tutorial test page to assure that the test itself contains no errors. **What else do I need to make the test page executable?**

- Page type is "test"
- URL is `/SandBox.MyTest`

I read in the [FitNesse UserGuide](http://butunclebob.com/FitNesse.UserGuide.SpecialPages), that there are special pages that always get included at the top, namely `PageHeader` and `SetUp` for tests. But neither of these exist:

- `/FitLibraryWeb.SpiderFixture.SpiderTutorial.StartingWithSpider.SetUp`
- `/FitLibraryWeb.SpiderFixture.SpiderTutorial.SetUp`
- `/FitLibraryWeb.SpiderFixture.SetUp`
- `/FitLibraryWeb.SetUp`

(same for `PageHeader`)

**[1] The test page starts as follows:**

```
!define spider {''!-SpiderFixture-!''}
!| fitlibrary.spider.SpiderFixture |

| ''start spider with'' | chrome |
| ''shutdown browser automatically'' | false |

| ''get url'' | http://localhost:${FITNESSE_PORT}/FitLibraryWeb.TemplateFixture |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out... [The ClassPath documentation](http://butunclebob.com/FitNesse.UserGuide.ClassPath) was the missing link:

> For a given **SubWiki** of test pages, you can specify to FitNesse where
>   it can find all of the fixture classes it needs by supplying a
>   so-called ClassPath definition, which is a full absolute filepath to
>   the directory that contains the package (in Java) or assembly (in C#)
>   in which all the compiled classes can be found. Simply include a
>   ClassPath definition on the **main page of your SubWiki**.

*(emphasis by me)*

So, the code that I searched for, was in `FitLibraryWeb`:

```
!*< paths and defines
#!path ../bin
!path lib/fitlibraryweb-2.0.jar
!path fitlibrary-2.0.jar
#!path ../../fitlibrary/bin
!path lib/*.jar
!define TEST_RUNNER {fitlibrary.suite.FitLibraryServer}
!define REGRACE_LINK {false}
!define REGRACE_TOC {false}

*!
```

These definitions apply for all sub pages in the *SubWiki*. I copied it to my `SandBox` main page, changed the type of this page to `Suite` and now it works!